# Glassfish - JEE6 - Use of Interceptor to measure performance

Tags: glassfish, java-ee-6, introspection, performancecounter

For measuring execution time of methods, I've seen suggestions to use

```
public class PerformanceInterceptor {
   @AroundInvoke
   Object measureTime(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
   long beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
   Object obj = null;
   try {
      obj = ctx.proceed();
      return obj;
   }
   finally {
      time = System.currentTimeMillis() - beforeTime;
      // Log time
   }
}
```

Then put

```
@Interceptors(PerformanceInterceptor.class)
```

before whatever method you want measured.

Anyway I tried this and it seems to work fine.

I also added a

```
public static long countCalls = 0;
```

to the PerformanceInterceptor class and a

```
countCalls++;
```

to the measureTime() which also seems to work o.k.

With my newby hat on, I will ask if my use of the countCalls is o.k. i.e
that Glassfish/JEE6 is o.k. with me using static variables in a Java class that is
used as an Interceptor.... in particular with regard to thread safety. I know that
normally you are supposed to synchronize setting of class variables in Java, but I
don't know what the case is with JEE6/Glassfish. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not any additional thread safety provided by container in this case. Each bean instance does have its own instance of interceptor. As a consequence multiple thread can access static countCalls same time.

That's why you have to guard both reads and writes to it as usual. Other possibility is to use [AtomicLong](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html):

```
private static final AtomicLong callCount = new AtomicLong();

private long getCallCount() {
   return callCount.get();
}

private void increaseCountCall() {
   callCount.getAndIncrement();
}
```

As expected, these solutions will work only as long as all of the instances are in same JVM, for cluster shared storage is needed.