# JEE Performance Interceptor for Asynchronous method call

Tags: java, asynchronous, glassfish

A few years ago on Glassfish 3.1 I implemented a Performance Interceptor similar to the one talked about here :
[Glassfish - JEE6 - Use of Interceptor to measure performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544912/glassfish-jee6-use-of-interceptor-to-measure-performance)

It worked perfectly.
However now I want to use it to annotate Asychronous method calls. I am a bit puzzled.
Previously the annotated method returned a Boolean and I 
counted the successful ones.

```
  Object obj = null;
    try {
      obj = ctx.proceed();
      return obj;
   }
   finally {    
      if ( obj != null  ) {
         if ( obj instanceof Boolean ) {
            if ((Boolean)obj == true) {
               opStat.successfulCalls++;
             }
          }
          // Also record execution time of method    
   }
```

However, I'm puzzled about what happens to an asynchronous call.

It will return a Future instead of a Boolean.  So how do count the 
successful ones?
And is the "execution time" now just the time to launch the asynchronous request?

Is this Performance Interceptor useless for asynchronous method calls?
Is there another way to do it?
thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you try to count

Comment: I am trying to count how many of the method calls succeeded (return booleans with value true) or failed ( return boolean with value false.)

Comment: Ok. But it doesn't seem to have relation with execution time computation. Is it just a additional indicator to appreciate the execution time ?

Comment: Hi, I measure the execution time and also count the number of calls ( and whether they succeeded and failed.)  The link I provided in the original post did something similar i.e. measuring the execution time, and also counting the calls to the method. These values are saved to a static map in the PerformanceInterceptor class ( with synchronisation of the variables to protect them from concurrent writes.) Periodically I write these to a file and analyse them with some script cron jobs so any problems can be flagged.)